# submit button is depending on radio button

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

When a radio button is selected, the submit button should refer to the page associated with that radio button

**HTML**

```
<label class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="radio" name="betalen" value="bitcoin" />
  </span>
  <div style=" width: 320px;" class="form-control form-control-static">
      BITCOIN
  </div>
  <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback "></span>
</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback ">
  <label class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="radio" name="betalen" value="visa" />
  </span>
  <div style=" width: 320px;" class="form-control form-control-static">
      VISA
  </div>
  <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback "></span>
</label>
```

**The php code that I'm using. I found this code also on stackoverflow, but it doesn't work...**

```
<form action="pay-selector.php">
        <?php
    if (isset($_POST['betalen']) && $_POST['betalen'] == 'visa') {
        include('payvisa.php');
    } elseif (isset($_POST['betalen']) && $_POST['betalen'] == 'bitcoin') {
         include('paybitcoin.php');
    } 
 ?>
```

Do I something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st add  `onsubmit="setaction()"`  to form element.

```
<form action="#default_action" id="form_id" onsubmit="setaction()">
```

Then add id to bitcoin radio input

```
 <input type="radio" id="bitcoin" name="betalen" value="bitcoin" />
```

then add the following script

```
<script>
    function setaction() {

     var refer_to = ($('#bitcoin')[0].checked === true)? "paybitcoin.php" : "payvisa.php";

     $('form').attr('action', refer_to); 

     return false;
    }
</script>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, but it do not work... I did exactly what you had written but now my page reload and I stay on the same page

Comment: If my  answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.